# Validate custom constraint only if other constraint is passed

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, custom-validators

I have a basic custom validation setup as below:

```
@NotNullOrEmpty(message="{err.msg.required}", fieldName="Email")
@ValidEmail(message="{err.msg.validEmail}", fieldName="Email")
private String email;
```

However, if the email is empty, BOTH are triggered because of course, an empty email is not a valid email.

How do I trigger only `@NotNullOrEmpty` if its empty and only trigger `@ValidEmail` if it's non-empty?

Or is it possible to like

```
@Annotation1
@Annotation2 //trigger only if value has passed @Annotation1
```

What I have in mind is to edit my `ValidEmailValidator.isValid()` to return true if email is empty, but what if I want to validate empty emails in the future?

Comment: The standard way, implemented by all the standard annotations, is to consider an email valid if it's null or empty. So if you have a required email, you annotated the field with NotEmpty and Email. If you have a non-required email, you just annotate it with Email.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. So I guess I was right in my assumption then. Just needed some second-opinion to back it up. Add your comment as an answer. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way, implemented by all the standard annotations, is to consider an email valid if it's null or empty. So if you have a required email, you annotated the field with NotEmpty and Email. If you have a non-required email, you just annotate it with Email.

For the reference, here are the first lines of code of the standard EmailValidator:

```
if ( value == null || value.length() == 0 ) {
    return true;
}
```